# CSS resizing DIV on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS , when I resize my screen , it doesnt collapse , any idea why? this suppose to be at the center of the screen I want it to stay at the center but resize when the screen resolution change

Here is my code :

```
        <div style="position:relative; width:900px; margin:auto; text-align:center; font-size:25px;">
                <div style="margin-top:70px;"> 
                    <p style="line-height:1">some textttttttttt</p>
                    <p style="line-height:1">Another texthghghghgh </p>
                    <p style="margin-top:30px">different stuff here :</p>
                    <h2 style="color:#EE3969; font-size:45px"> first</h2>
                    <h2 style="color:#DE9540; font-size:45px"> second</h2>
                    <h2 style="color:#00AAC2; font-size:45px"> third</h2>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you specify `width:900px` so why would it collapse?

Comment: so removing the width , will make it work?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried? :) http://jsfiddle.net/3QCwM/

Comment: yes I figured it out , there was a code above missing it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first line of your code with this

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; margin:auto; text-align: center; font-size: 25px;">
```

Comment: What this guy said is right... setting the div to width to 100% will make it collapse... but only horizontally. It will not however make the content itself get smaller. It will only reflow the content to make it fit in a narrow space.

Comment: @TCD that what I want but its not working , I need it to make the content fit in a narrow space

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout, you can use JavaScript, or if you want a CSS answer, you use CSS3's Media Queries.

Using them you change the element's style properites depending on the Client's machine properties, such as Screen size, etc.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* properties for a screen with size 500px */
}
```

This way you can alter the CSS properties of the div, once you resize it.

Please note that you're using hardcoded `900px` value. Which would always force the browser to make it 900px, no matter how shorter you set the Screen's size by Resizing the Browser. For that thing, you can use CSS3's Media query. To change the Layout of the Document when Screen size gets shorter.

This way, you can have multiple styles for different screen sizes without having to worry about each of them and creating a single style for them.

Comment: I see your point but I have removed the width:900px and still its not resizing according to my browser , technically I don't need @media because the <p> should adjust

Comment: If `<p>` should adjust, then I think you need to be using `<p style="width: 100%">`. To adjust its own width. :) This way it would take up the 100% of the parent element.